# Why VS build automation gets all solution files?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I set a Visual Studio Build automation (on VS Team Services) for a team project containing several projects.

I need to create a build only for a wpf project instead the entire team project. So  I selected the specific project on the build configuration UI, like the following image.

[image]

However, when the build starts, I see that every single file in the entire team project is being GET.

Is it normal? My WPF project depends on another two projects, not the entire thing.

Is this a concern? How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build agent has no way to know that your project has only two references until it starts to build it.
You can narrow the number of file it will get by going to the tab "Repository" in the build definition and choose a mapping that is closer to the project. But don't forget to include all the dependencies

Comment: I see what you say. If this is a common practice I will keep this way. Thanks.